# Insert JSON string into Postgres and return field

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I want to insert a JSON string into a Postgres table with a jsonb field and want the insert query to return a part of the JSON. For example, I want to return the id in the example below. What goes on the question marks?

```
insert into mytable (myjson)
values ('{"id":123}') returning ???
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the `->>` operator to extract the value of the `id` attribute:

```
insert into mytable (myjson)
values ('{"id":123}') 
returning (myjson ->> 'id');
```